# Covering paired squares on a $10 \times 10$ board

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

In a game, the board is a $10 \times 10$  table (in the style of a chessboard). Two players make moves in turns. In a single step, a player covers two neighboring free cells of the table by $2\times 1$ tile. The player who cannot make a step loses the game. Who has a winning strategy - the player who starts the game or his opponent?

Comment: @almagest Let us consider 2 x 1 tile, for instance.

Comment: I think this game is called Domineering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This game is called [Cram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram_(game)) and the second player has a winning strategy. For every domino the first player places, the second player places a domino at the same spot rotated $180^\circ$ around the original board's centre, thus always leaving a $C_2$-symmetric board to the first player; this is always possible at every move because of the symmetry and because there is no way a domino can be placed "centrally" (either a centre square or edge) to ruin the strategy. Eventually the first player will be unable to move and lose, handing the win to the second player.

Answer (score 2):

**Correction.**

My answer is marked as correct though it is in fact inaccurate. The game the OP is describing is called Cram, see [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram_(game)), in which an argument is discussed as to why the second player will have a winning strategy in the case of a $10 \times 10$ board.

**Old answer.**

I initially misrecognised the problem as a very similar game called Domineering, which also has [its own Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domineering). Curiously, unlike Cram, Domineering seems to lack the symmetry to have straightforward strategies like Cram does, and finding an optimal strategy for Domineering seems to be hard. For a $10 \times 10$ board, the Wikipedia page claims that a perfect strategy was found in the Master thesis of Nathan Bullock.

Comment: You're wrong. The problem never specified that one player must place dominos horizontally and the other vertically. Because of this, the game is actually [Cram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram_(game)) and the second player wins by a point symmetry argument. See my answer.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel You're correct, I seem to have glossed over this.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I chose to keep the answer in place since it's already marked correct, but I've altered it to accomodate my inaccuracy.